# PHP Posting to external script and receiving response

Tags: php, forms, curl, request, response

There is an online browser game that I am making a fan site for, where you can submit your character name and other members of the site can rate it etc. Now, I'm trying to prevent people from impersonating other people by listing their character as someone elses, in order to do so I plan to post to the login script on the game site and receive the response whether it successfully logged in or not, if not then they can't add that character to their account, but if it did login then they can.

I'm wondering whether this is possible, I've looked at methods with cURL before, but not found anything conclusive that would work in this way.

I don't have any example code to use, but it should be pretty much straight forward, a form with a username and password field.

Answer (score 0):

You have entered too few informations to expect getting specific answer.

Try to use [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.gamesite.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "username=value1&password=value2&function=authenticate");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$login_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

if ($login_output == "OK") { ... } else { ... }
```

But you should check at least source code of website to find out the variable names and correctly added them to postfields.

If you have the account, you can login and check firebug site tab to find out how the server respond if ok and use it in `$login_output`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need the form with the username and password, so, you'll be able of retrieve the user and login from the third party web. When you'll have it, you need to send a cURL petition with this data **as the third party do**. I mean, go to the 3rd party web, and inspect the form. If the form is sending the post data to 'logInUser.php' with the post data being 'usergame=USERNAME&passgame=PASSWORD' you'll have to POST your form data against 'logInUser.php' with the data in the same format as the web do.

Problem is, would your users give you their passwords? Because if you want to use cURL to login to the other web, you'll need their username and password.

You should check if the web has Oauth (http://oauth.net/), and if so, you should use it.